# How to get all the values from input fields using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this structure.

```
<PlayerFormBox>
   - <PlayerForm>
```

I add new form dynamic, I want to know how I can get hold of all input values
from the form in PlayerFormBox on submit

```
<PlayerFormBox> 
....

render: function () {
    var formFields = [];
    for(i = 0; i < this.state.numOfPlayers; i++){
        formFields.push(<PlayerForm key={i} />);
    }
    return (
        <div className="playerBox">
            <input value="add field" type="button" onClick={this.addField} />
            <form id = "form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                {formFields}
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}



<PlayerForm>

var PlayerForm = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <input key={this.props.index} type="text" name="name">
        </div>
    );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably make the `PlayerForm` component to trigger an event when the value changes and store these values in the `PlayerFormBox`'s state. This way you'll have all the values upon submission. In fact, for React, it's a good practice not to submit forms directly. It's a good practice to use your `input` fields to build a `model` and then process and submit this `model`, via Ajax, using a request library that works on the browser like [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios).

So, in the `PlayerForm`, make it to trigger an event:

```
var PlayerForm = React.createClass({

handleChange: function(event) {
    // it's passing the index and the value as parameters
    this.props.onChange(this.props.index, event.value);
}

render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <input key={this.props.index} onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="name">
        </div>
    );
})
```

Now, create a `PlayerFormChanged` function on the  `PlayerFormBox`, then pass it as a handler when you create a new `PlayerForm`:

```
for(i = 0; i < this.state.numOfPlayers; i++){
    formFields.push(<PlayerForm key={i} onValueChange={onPlayerFormValueChange}/>);
}
```

Now in the `onPlayerFormValueChange` function, build a model, something like this:

```
onPlayerFormValueChange: function(index, value) {
     // now you should set this.state.model[index] = value
     // Use the imutability helpers here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html
     // this will result on a setState that will render everything again accordingly 
}
```

Now, upon submission, `PlayerForm` has the model on it's state.