# How to get the value of an input field using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following React component:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = this.title;
        console.log(title);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            ...
            <form className="form-horizontal">
                ...
                <input type="text" className="form-control" ref={(c) => this.title = c} name="title" />
                ...
            </form>
            ...
            <button type="button" onClick={this.onSubmit} className="btn">Save</button>
            ...
        );
    }

};
```

The console is giving me `undefined` - any ideas what's wrong with this code?

Comment: `this.onSubmit.bind(this);`

Comment: Nice - want to add it as answer and I'll tick it off (?)

Comment: what about `e.target.value` without the bind?

Comment: wouldn't e.target.value be targetting the button, not the input field?

Comment: You need to bind the `onSubmit` method to the submit button (DOM element) when clicked (i.e. `onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}`). And if you'd like to access the value of the title input in the form you can use `onSubmit(event) { const title = event.target.elements.title.value; }`.

Comment: I see that a few people have recommended using `this.onSubmit.bind(this)`, it will work, but you'll be wasting resources doing that, you need to do the following in the constructor: `this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)`

In this example every time the submit button is clicked a new function is created and returned from the `bind()` method, you wanna make sure you do it only once, therefore you put it in the constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all the values from input fields using ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31922272/608639)

Comment: In fact, _don't_ use `bind`, at all. If you want `this` conservation, use arrow functions. That's literally what they're for. By using `bind` you're increasing your bug surface, and you're burdening your constructor with code it shouldn't be responsible for. The limitations of React are not your constructor's problem, especially not when `evt => this.handler(evt)` works perfectly fine because keeping `this` to mean the same thing across the function call is literally what we added the feature to JavaScript for.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use constructor under the class MyComponent extends React.Component

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

Then you will get the result of title

Comment: Also, if you're using hooks, here's [how to get input value with react hooks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91TIUURx5JM)

Answer (score 517):

There are three answers here, depending on the version of React you're (forced to) work(ing) with, and whether you want to use hooks.

### First things first:

It's important to understand how React works, so you can do things properly (protip: it's *super* worth running through [the React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) on the React website. It's well written, and covers all the basics in a way that actually explains how to do things). "Properly" here means that you're not writing a web page, you're writing the user interface for an application that happens to be rendered in a browser; all the actual user interface work happens in React, not in "what you're used to from writing a web page" (this is why React apps really are "apps", not "web pages").

React applications are rendered based off of two things:

1. the component's properties as declared by whichever parent creates an instance of that component, which the parent can modify throughout its lifecycle, and
2. the component's own internal state, which it can modify itself throughout its own lifecycle.

What you're expressly *not* doing when you use React is generating HTML elements and then using those: when you tell React to use an `<input>`, for instance, you are not creating an HTML input element, you are instead telling React to create a React input object that happens to render as an HTML input element when you compile your React app for the web, with event handling that is controlled by React.

When using React, what you're doing is generating application UI elements that present the user with (often manipulable) data, with user interaction changing the state of your application in a way that *you* define - actions performed by the user may update a component's props or state, which React uses as a signal to generate a new UI representation for changed components, which *may* cause an update of part of your application interface to reflect the new state.

In this programming model, the app's internal state is the final authority, rather than "the UI your users look at and interact with": if a user tries to type something in an input field, and you did not write anything to handle that, nothing will happen: the UI is a reflection of the application state, not the other way around. Effectively, the browser DOM is almost an afterthought in this programming model: it just happens to be a super convenient UI framework that the entire planet is virtually guaranteed to have access to (but it's not the only one React knows how to work with)

### A specific example

So with that covered, let's look how a user interacting with an input element works in React. First, we need to get to having a UI element for the user to interact with:

1. You wrote a component to manage (i.e. both store and present) some string data for your users, with an `onChange` function for handling user data.
2. Your component's rendering code is used by React to generate a virtual DOM that contains an `input` component (not a DOM `<input>` element), and binds your `onChange` handler to that component so that it can be called with React event data (so note that this is not a DOM `change` event listener, and does not get the same event data that regular DOM event listeners do).
3. The React library then translates that virtual DOM into a UI users can interact with, and that it will update as the application state changes. Since it's running in the browser, it builds an HTML input element.

Then, your user tries to actually interact with that input element:

1. Your user clicks on the input element and starts typing.
2. **Nothing happens to the input element yet. Instead, the input events get intercepted by React and killed off immediately**.
3. React turns the browser event into a React event, and calls the `onChange` function for the virtual DOM component with the React event data.
4. That function *may* do something, based on what how you wrote it, and in this case you almost certainly wrote it to update the state of your component with what the user (tried to) type.
5. If a state update gets scheduled, React will run that state update in the near future, which will trigger a render pass after the update.
6. During the render pass, it checks to see if the state is actually different, and if so, it generates a temporary second virtual DOM, which it compares to (a part of) your application's virtual DOM, determines which set of add/update/remove operations it needs to perform on you application's virtual DOM so that it looks the same as the new temporary one, then applies those operations and throws away the temporary virtual DOM again.
7. It then updates the UI so that it reflects what the virtual DOM now looks like.
8. And after all of that, we finally have an updated DOM on the page the user is actually looking at, and they see what they typed in the input element.

So this is completely different from the regular browser model: instead of the user updating the UI data by typing into a text box *first* and our code reading "the current value of that text box" to figure out what the state is *second*, React already knows what the state is, and uses events to update the state *first*, which leads to a UI update *second*.

And it is important to remember that all of this happens effectively instantly, so to your user it *looks* like they typed text into an input element in the same way they would for any random web page, but under the hood things couldn't be more different while still leading to the same result.

So, with that covered, let's look at how to get values from elements in React:

### Component classes and ES6 (React 16+ and 15.5 transitional)

As of React 16 (and soft-starting with 15.5) the `createClass` call is no longer supported, and class syntax needs to be used. This changes two things: the obvious class syntax, but also the `this`context binding that `createClass` can do "for free", so to ensure things still work make sure you're using "fat arrow" notation for `this` context preserving anonymous functions in `onWhatever` handlers, such as the `onChange` we use in the code here:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.reset();
  }

  reset() {
    // Always set the initial state in its own function, so that
    // you can trivially reset your components at any point.
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // ...
      <input value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={evt => this.updateInputValue(evt)}/>
      // ...
    );
  },

  updateInputValue(evt) {
    const val = evt.target.value;
    // ...       
    this.setState({
      inputValue: val
    });
  }
});
```

You may also have seen people use `bind` in their constructor for all their event handling functions, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
  ...
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <element onclick={this.handler}/>
    ...
  );
}
```

Don't do that.

Almost any time you're using `bind`, the proverbial "you're doing it wrong" applies. Your class already defines the object prototype, and so already defines the instance context. Don't put `bind` of top of that; use normal event forwarding instead of duplicating all your function calls in the constructor, because that duplication increases your bug surface, and makes it much harder to trace errors because the problem might be in your constructor instead of where you call your code.

"But then it's constantly making and throwing away functions on rerenders!" and that may be true but you're not going to notice. Nor are your users. If event handler garbage collection is your performance bottleneck, so much has already gone wrong that you need to stop and rethink your design: the reason React works so incredibly well is because it does not update the entire UI, it only updates the parts that change, and in a well designed UI, the time that most of your UI spends not changing drastically outnumbers the time small parts of your UI spend updating.

### Function components with hooks (React 16.8+)

As of React 16.8 the function component (i.e. literally just a function that takes some `props` as argument can be used as if it's an instance of a component class, without ever writing a class) can also be given state, through the use of [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

If you don't need full class code, and a single instance function will do, then you can now use the `useState` hook to get yourself a single state variable, and its update function, which works roughly the same as the above examples, except without the "universal" `setState` function call and using one dedicated state setter for each value you're working with:

```
import { useId, useState } from 'react';

function myFunctionalComponentFunction(props) {
  const id = useId();
  const [input, setInput] = useState(props?.value ?? '');
  return (
    <div>
    <label htmlFor={id}>Please specify:</label>
    <input id={id} value={input} onInput={e => setInput(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Previously the unofficial distinction between classes and function components was "function components don't have state", so we can't hide behind that one anymore: the difference between function components and classes components can be found spread over several pages in the very well-written [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) (no shortcut one liner explanation to conveniently misinterpret for you!) which you should read so that you know what you're doing and can thus know whether you picked the best (whatever that means for you) solution to program yourself out of a problem you're having.

### React 15 and below, using legacy ES5 and `createClass`

To do things properly, your component has a state value, which is shown via an input field, and we can update it by making that UI element send change events back into the component:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      inputValue: ''
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      //...
      <input value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.updateInputValue}/>
      //...
    );
  },

  updateInputValue: function(evt) {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: evt.target.value
    });
  }
});
```

So we tell React to use the `updateInputValue` function to handle the user interaction, use `setState` to schedule the state update, and the fact that `render` taps into `this.state.inputValue` means that when it rerenders after updating the state, the user will see the update text based on what they typed.

**addendum based on comments**

Given that UI inputs represent state values (consider what happens if a user closes their tab midway, and the tab is restored. Should all those values they filled in be restored? If so, that's state). That might make you feel like a large form needs tens or even a hundred input forms, but React is about modeling your UI in a maintainable way: you do not have 100 independent input fields, you have groups of related inputs, so you capture each group in a component and then build up your "master" form as a collection of groups.

```
MyForm:
  render:
    <PersonalData/>
    <AppPreferences/>
    <ThirdParty/>
     ...
```

This is also much easier to maintain than a giant single form component. Split up groups into Components with state maintenance, where each component is only responsible for tracking a few input fields at a time.

You may also feel like it's "a hassle" to write out all that code, but that's a false saving: developers-who-are-not-you, including future you, actually benefit greatly from seeing all those inputs hooked up explicitly, because it makes code paths much easier to trace. However, you can always optimize. For instance, you can write a state linker

```
MyComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      firstName: this.props.firstName || "",
      lastName: this.props.lastName || "" 
      ...: ...
      ...
    }
  },
  componentWillMount() {
    Object.keys(this.state).forEach(n => {
      let fn = n + 'Changed';
      this[fn] = evt => {
        let update = {};
        update[n] = evt.target.value;
        this.setState(update);
      });
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return Object.keys(this.state).map(n => {
      <input
        key={n} 
        type="text"
        value={this.state[n]}
        onChange={this[n + 'Changed']}/>
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I've read a few online articles which say that using too much state is a bad idea. In one particular form of my application I have about 100 form fields. Defining a function to save the state feels like an unnecessarily arduous way of doing things. If I can use onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}, this seems like a good way to get the value (then if I want, set the components state) - I would appreciate some comments on this.

Comment: so write smarter code. form inputs are most definitely state (consider what happens if a user closes their tab midway, and the tab is restored. Should all those values they filled in be restored? yes? *that's state*), so write a bit of state maintenance code. Facebook has hundreds of form values, too, and their solution to the madness was React. It works *really* well. One way to make your code a little easier, while still using state, is to use [two way state linking](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html), again, explained on the React site. Worth reading! =)

Comment: Also note that "100 fields" is mostly irrelevant: split up your form, because it's not 100 elements, it's several sections, each with a number of inputs, so apply good design and make each section its own component, with grouping components for form groups. This typically makes a component responsible for less than 10 inputs, and suddenly your information architecture makes a *lot* more sense. The form submit, as a browser action, of course just sees "your form" and submits everything in one go. Clean, targetted UI design.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I did however notice that state linking has been deprecated as of React v15.

Comment: Sure, so you hit up google or npmjs.com and then you search for what is a suitable replacement in React 5 context. Or you roll your own. I've update the answer but at this point I've pretty much written you a tutorial instead of an answer, which is a little silly given that there are lots of tutorials online already, but there you go. Hope it helps, and remember that open source is first about finding whether someone's already done what you need to do and using that, instead of feeling like you need to solve every problem yourself.

Comment: This sample gives me Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: forgot to use arrow notation for the event handler, too. updated.

Comment: This is the recommended approach, but I am reluctant to bet on it.

The browser has already handle the state for all those form elements, and we are writing code to keep it in sync with the React JS.  That's extra code for every fields.  This doesn't sound write to me.

My way to do this is don't use the React state to maintain its state.  Just let the state kept in the browser.  When you need it, you can get the value out by using jQuery $('#id').val().

Comment: @JasonChing then you've simply built potential bugs into your code. React is not a "be all, end all" solution to web pages, it's a framework for building interfaces, and *it* is responsible for state management and actual UI rendering as afterthought (your users don't interact with the DOM, they interact with React. The DOM updates are simply an asynchronous (but incredibly fast) last step so that the UI visually reflect the state). If you want to bypass that, the more important question is: why are you using React? Because the best sign you're using it wrong is combining React and jQuery.

Comment: There's a typo here, the `:` after `render` is not necessary.

Comment: so there were - removed. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: wouldn't it be cleaner to get rid of the `updateInputValue` function and do this: `<input value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={e=> this.setState({'inputValue':e.target.value})}/>`?

Comment: Cleaner? No. Terser? Yes. It's entirely up to you if you need that terseness, most people want to "do something" with data that's coming in (like validating before allowing it through) so blindly allowing it through is often not useful. If you want terse _and_ clean, you now also get hooks, which I'd recommend uses instead. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: does this strategy apply even if it's a password field?  trying to know how to dispatch a login form submission with the appropriate values.  is storing the password in the component state really a recommended approach?

Comment: How is storing it in the component, for as long as you need it to send it off, any different from storing it in a queryable-by-everything-on-the-page form field? Just don't hold on to sensitive data for any longer than you need it to do what it's required for.

Comment: In the last code block a } is lost, at the end of the line <input value={input} onInput={e => setInput(e.target.value)}/>

Comment: so it was: added it in, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Also remember there are `controlled` (using `value`) and `uncontrolled` (using `defaultValue`) way of initializing the input. [ref](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled)

Comment: That's not React, that's something Mui added on top.

Answer (score 29):

Managed to get the input field value by doing something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);

this.state = {
  username : ''
}

this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}


updateInput(event){
this.setState({username : event.target.value})
}


handleSubmit(){
console.log('Your input value is: ' + this.state.username)
//Send state to the server code
}



render(){
return (
    <div>
    <input type="text" onChange={this.updateInput}></input>
    <input type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} ></input>
    </div>
  );
}
} 

//output
//Your input value is: x
```

Comment: Why using "setState"? This involves a re-rendering..isn't it?

Answer (score 24):

**In react 16, I use**

```
<Input id="number" 
       type="time" 
       onChange={(evt) => { console.log(evt.target.value); }} />
```

Comment: doesn't work if the field was populated automatically on age load

Answer (score 15):

## In Function Component

#### useState

Returns a stateful value, and a function to update it.
During the initial render, the returned state `(state)` is the same as the value passed as the first argument `(initialState)`.
The `setState` function is used to update the state. It accepts a new state value and enqueues a re-render of the component. 
src ---> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

#### useRef

`useRef` returns a mutable ref object whose `.current` property is initialized to the passed argument `(initialValue)`. The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component. 
src ---> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState('');
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setVal(inputRef.current.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input ref={inputRef} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

      <p>Submit Value: <b>{val}</b></p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Give the `<input>` a unique id

```
<input id='title' ...>
```

and then use the [standard Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to reference it in the DOM

```
const title = document.getElementById('title').value
```

No need to continually update the React state with every keypress. Simply get the value when it's required.

Comment: That would be a very bad practiced in React

Comment: @DivinesLight can you please explain why?

Answer (score 7):

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
     state={
         value:'',
         show:''
      }

handleChange=(e)=>{
  this.setState({value:e.target.value})
}

submit=()=>{
   this.setState({show:this.state.value})
}

render(){
    return(
        <>
          <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
             <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
             <input type="submit" />
          </form>
          <h2>{this.state.show}</h2>
        </>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

****In Function Component :-****

```
export default function App(){

const [state, setState] = useState({
        value:'',
        show:''
    });

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState({value: e.target.value})
}

const submit = () => {
    setState({show: state.value})
}

return(
        <>
            <form onSubmit={()=>submit()}>
                <input type="text" value={state.value} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)} />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
            <h2>{state.show}</h2>
        </>
)}
```

Answer (score 6):

I succeeded in doing this by binding `this` to the function
`updateInputValue(evt)` with

`this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);`

However input `value={this.state.inputValue}` ...
turned out to be no good idea.

Here's the full code in babel ES6 :

```
class InputField extends React.Component{

    
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   //this.state={inputfield: "no value"};   
   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick(){
   console.log("trying to add picture url");
   console.log("value of input field : "+this.state.inputfield);
   
  }
 
  updateInputValue(evt){
    //console.log("input field updated with "+evt.target.value);
    this.state={inputfield: evt.target.value};   
    
  }

  render(){
    var r; 
    r=<div><input type="text" id="addpixinputfield" 
            onChange={this.updateInputValue} />
      <input type="button" value="add" id="addpix" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>;    
    return r;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- React Version: 17.0.1

  a) Using Functional Components

  b) Manage state using hook: useState().

Write and Run code as above:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const InputElement = () => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');

  return (
   <div> 
        <input
              onChange={(e) => {
                  setInputText(e.target.value);
                   }                   
             }
             placeholder='Enter Text'
       />
       {inputText}
   </div>
 );
}
```

The solving scheme algorithm is similar to a two-way data binding:

> input <=> DATA_MODEL <=> Label_Text

Answer (score 2):

your error is because of you use class and when use class we need to bind the functions with This in order to work well. anyway there are a lot of tutorial why we should "this" and what is "this" do in javascript.

if you correct your submit button it should be work:

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} className="btn">Save</button>
```

and also if you want to show value of that input in console you should use var title = this.title.value;

Comment: this link might be helpful if you want to know more about "this"

Comment: https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56#.ab7z5tgpw

Answer (score 2):

This simplest way is to use **arrow function**

Your code with arrow functions

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = this.title;
    console.log(title);
}

render(){
    return (
        ...
        <form className="form-horizontal">
            ...
            <input type="text" className="form-control" ref={(c) => this.title = c} name="title" />
            ...
        </form>
        ...
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onSubmit} className="btn">Save</button>
        ...
    );
}
```

};

Answer (score 1):

```
// On the state
constructor() {
  this.state = {
   email: ''
 }
}

// Input view ( always check if property is available in state {this.state.email ? this.state.email : ''}

<Input 
  value={this.state.email ? this.state.email : ''} 
  onChange={event => this.setState({ email: event.target.value)}
  type="text" 
  name="emailAddress" 
  placeholder="johdoe@somewhere.com" />
```

Comment: while your answer could be good for the question it's always better to add some explanation. Please take 2 minutes to add it. This will improve your answer also for future users.

Comment: sure, I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an input value without adding 'onChange' function.

Just add to the input element a 'ref attr:

And then use this.refs to get the input value when you need it.

Comment: This is not recommended anymore.

Comment: You can use them, but it's recommended to keep the data flow in one direction using props and callbacks.

Comment: It would be good to add an example of adding refs correctly, I.e. Using a ref callback instead of a legacy string.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ref into: `ref='title'` and delete `name='title'`
Then delete `var title = this.title` and write:

```
console.log(this.refs.title.value)
```

Also you should add `.bind(this)` to `this.onSubmit`

(It worked in my case which was quite similar, but instead of `onClick` I had `onSubmit={...}` and it was put in form ( `<form onSubmit={...} ></form>)`)

Answer (score 0):

if you use class component then only 3 steps- first you need to declare state for your input filed for example **this.state = {name:''}**. Secondly, you need to write a function for setting the state when it changes in bellow example it is **setName()** and finally you have to write the input jsx for example                 **< input value={this.name} onChange = {this.setName}/>**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class InputComponents extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             name:'',
             agree:false
        }
        this.setName = this.setName.bind(this);
        this.setAgree=this.setAgree.bind(this);
    }

    setName(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.value);
        this.setState({
            name:e.target.value
        })
    }
    setAgree(){
        this.setState({
            agree: !this.state.agree
        }, function (){
            console.log(this.state.agree);
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.agree} onChange={this.setAgree}></input>
                < input value={this.state.name} onChange = {this.setName}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default InputComponents
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = this.title.value; //added .value
    console.log(title);
}

render(){
    return (
        ...
        <form className="form-horizontal">
            ...
            <input type="text" className="form-control" ref={input => this.title = input} name="title" />
            ...
        </form>
        ...
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onSubmit} className="btn">Save</button>
        ...
    );
}

};
```

Answer (score -1):

using uncontrolled fields:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.neededField.value);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            ...
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="form-horizontal">
                ...
                <input type="text" name="neededField" className="form-control" ref={(c) => this.title = c}/>
                ...
            </form>
            ...
            <button type="button" className="btn">Save</button>
            ...
        );
    }

};
```

Comment: why are there an unused ref and 2 name properties on your input field?