# Can't update parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to edit an input value in a child component and send to the parent
:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-rain-skoss?file=/src/Editlabel.js:0-389

Parent:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import EditLabel from "./Editlabel";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("newName", newName);
  }, [newName]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <EditLabel
        value={"hello"}
        click={(changedName) => {
          setNewName(changedName);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const EditLabel = ({ value, click }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(value);

  return (
    <>
      <input type={"text"} placeholder={name}></input>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          setName(e.target.value);
          click(name);
        }}
      >
        Edit
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default EditLabel;
```

However, the console logs "hello" and then it just logs empty strings.
How can I make it work?

Comment: `e.target` is the button, not the input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of an input field using ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683770/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-input-field-using-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this on your child's input box

```
<input type={"text"} placeholder={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `EditLabel` to use a ref to capture the input value:

```
const EditLabel = ({ value, click }) => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputRef} type={"text"} placeholder={value}></input>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          click(inputRef.current.value);
        }}
      >
        Edit
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Update `App` to use the values it gets via the `click` callback:

```
export default function App() {
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState("hello");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("newName", newName);
  }, [newName]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <EditLabel
        value={newName}
        click={(changedName) => {
          setNewName(changedName);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit epic-johnson-tewd3]