# Copy to clipboard a value from an input in React with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-ref

Having the following code snippet:

```
      <div>
        <Input
          id='id'
          disabled
          value='test'
        />
        <Button
          onClick={copyToClipboard}
        />
      </div>
```

The button, when clicked, must copy the value from input, which is already set to `test`.

So, `copyToClipboard` must perform the operation:

```
  const copyToClipboard = () => {
   ...
  };
```

How I've tried:

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';

...

const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = useState('');
const textAreaRef = useRef(null);

  function copyToClipboard(e) {
    textAreaRef.current.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    e.target.focus();
    setCopySuccess('Copied!');
  }

...

              <div>
                <Input
                  ref={textAreaRef}
                  id='id'
                  value='test'
                />
                <Button
                  onClick={copyToClipboard}
                />        
              </div>
```

It has an error saying: `Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)` for `textAreaRef.current.select();`. I'm using React with Typescript.

Comment: `e => navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.target.value)` ?

Comment: That's `e.target.value`

Comment: does this answer your question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683770/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-input-field-using-reactjs

Comment: @JafarJabr no, I have updated my question with the method I've tried

Comment: That's just TypeScript and unrelated to the original question, check if it's null and if it is handle accordingly or add a `!.` instead of a `.` if you think it's not...

Comment: @LeoMessi it would be helpful if you create sandBox

Answer (score 0):

`textAreaRef.current` is possibly `null`. In fact, `null` is the default initial value you've set the `textAreaRef` to.

```
const textAreaRef = useRef(null);
```

What the warning is saying that `textAreaRef.current` is possibly `null` but you are accessing it in an unsafe way in order to invoke the `select` function.

You *might* be able to use the Optional Chaining operator ([Typescript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)):

```
textAreaRef.current?.select();
```

Or you just use a null-check/guard-clause:

```
textAreaRef.current && textAreaRef.current.select();
```

Comment: I've tried with this method but I think that typescript doesn't let it work, do you know what type to assing to `e` from `copyToClipboard(e)`? And after adding `textAreaRef.current && textAreaRef.current.select();` is says `Property 'select' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)`

Comment: @LeoMessi Unfortunately, no, I'm minimally versed in Typescript. You might be able to declare it `any` until you can find a more accurate/restrictive type declaration. I think it'd be something like `HTMLInputElement` assuming `Input` is rendering an `input` tag and attaching the ref to it.