# How to get value of data custom-attribute in JSX / React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Let's say I create a data-custom attribute in JSX element to save some meta-data about that element.

Like:

```
return (
    <button data-customData="red" onClick={(ev) => { console.log(ev.target.customData)}}>Teste</button>
)
```

If I try to acess the data-custom attribute like you see in the code I will get `undefined`.

But If I try something like `ev.target.style` or `ev.target.id` I will not get undefined.

What is the difference and how can we acess this value ?

Comment: `dataset.color`

Comment: `ev.target.value;` Referencing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683770/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-input-field-using-reactjs

Comment: `ev.target.dataset.customData`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-can-i-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Comment: ```ev.target.dataset.customData```  and  ```ev.target.getAttribute('data-customData')``` work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not calling the right value, you are calling a property called `customData` but the attribute name is `data-customData`, and in order to get the value you need to change how you call the attribute using the `getAttribute` function that the element (ev.target) provides

```
return (
 <button
  data-customData="red"
  onClick={(ev) => {
   const element = ev.target;
   console.log(element.getAttribute("data-customData"));
  }}
 >
   Click Me
 </button>
)
```

The thing you're trying to is not a very common pattern and if you want to get a value from the user you should use the right control (input, radio, select) instead of using a data attribute.